# Make a JQuery Accordion scroll through all panes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I want to take my JQuery Accordion and, with it starting open on the last element, have each pane successively drop down (to make it clear to the user that there are other panes of content available for them to view).  I can am using Accordion.accordion("activate", index) to change the open pane, but it only works once (successive calls don't seem to have any effect?).

Right now the code below initializes the accordion and activates pane one, but doesn't have any effect on pane two.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        nyah = $("#accordion").accordion({
            event: "mouseover",
            animated: "bounceslide"
        });
        nyah.accordion("activate", 1);
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            i++;
        }
        nyah.accordion("activate", 2);
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id = "accordion">
<h3><a href="#">One</a></h3>
<div><img src="1.png" alt="" /></div>
<h3><a href="#">Two</a></h3>
<div><img src="2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<h3><a href="#">Three</a></h3>
<div><img src="3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It does support multiple activations: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/v2FCJ/.**

However, your code is triggering the second activate before the first one is done.  The accordion does not apparently support queuing commands.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle link, that was super useful

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this using setTimeout.  I think your problem is that you're calling activate before the first activate finishes.

http://jsfiddle.net/xgFpD/1/

```
$(function() {
    var accordionCount = $("#accordion h3").length;

    nyah = $("#accordion").accordion({
        event: "mouseover",
        animated: "bounceslide"
    });



    function doExpand(index) {

        nyah.accordion("activate", index);

        if (index + 1 <= accordionCount) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                doExpand(index + 1);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    doExpand(0);
});
```

Comment: noticed I was starting with 1 instead of 0.  Updated and now it's smoother, shows 0 for a second before swapping to 1.